# Combining several queries into 1 new query

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I have a table that consists of all of our agency records.  I have several queries set up that count something specific about these records and each query groups them all by date.  What I am trying to figure out is how I can combine these queries into one new query.  Right now, I run each one, put them into Excel and then do a vlookup and combine them into one.  Here are just two of my queries.

Query #1:

```
select 
    LocationStateAbr,
    count(LocationStateAbr) as "Total Agencies" 
from
    [PROD_Agency].[dbo].[AgAgency]
where 
    StatusId = ' ' 
    and BusinessId in ('b', 'C') 
    and TypeId in ('A', 'C', 'F', 'I', 'X') 
group by 
    LocationStateAbr
order by 
    LocationStateAbr ASC
```

Query #2:

```
select 
    LocationStateAbr,
    count(LocationStateAbr) as "New Agencies" 
from
    [PROD_Agency].[dbo].[AgAgency]
where 
    year(AppointedDt) = 2018 
    and StatusId = ' ' 
    and BusinessId in ('b', 'C') 
    and TypeId in ('A', 'C', 'F', 'I', 'X') 
group by 
    LocationStateAbr
order by 
    LocationStateAbr ASC
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two queries into one using CASE. In your case it would be something like this:

```
select 
    LocationStateAbr,
    count(case when StatusId = ' ' 
          and BusinessId in ('b', 'C') 
          and TypeId in ('A', 'C', 'F', 'I', 'X') then 1 else null end) as "Total Agencies",
    count(case when year(AppointedDt) = 2018 
          and StatusId = ' ' 
          and BusinessId in ('b', 'C') 
          and TypeId in ('A', 'C', 'F', 'I', 'X') the 1 else null end) as "New Agencies"
FROM
   [PROD_Agency].[dbo].[AgAgency]
group by 
    LocationStateAbr
order by 
    LocationStateAbr ASC
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Wendy Glad I helped :) If the answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted (by clicking the check sign on the top left of my answer) so that other will also know it

Comment: Done!  :)  One follow up - how would I include a total at the bottom of each column - Total Agencies and New Agencies?